# How to improve my PHP adding script?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script, which updates my table's column and writes an id to it.

I need to check whether the column is empty or not.  If it is not, I add a `,`.

```
$subs = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT subscribed_user_id FROM users WHERE user_id=".(int)$_GET['user']));

$subs_array = array();

$subs_array=explode(',', $subs['subscribed_user_id']);

if(!in_array($_COOKIE['user_id'], $subs_array))
{
    if($subs['subscribed_user_id']=='')
    {
        $add='';
    } else {
        $add = $subs['subscribed_user_id'].',';
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET subers=subers+1, subscribed_user_id='".$add.$_COOKIE['user_id']."' WHERE user_id=".(int)$_GET['user']);
}
```

I have an idea: always add `,`.  But when I select it, I don't use the full length of the array.  But, for example `array.length-2`, I think that it is not OK and I need to know how I can improve this script.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do? Just add a , if the column is not empty? Why? Your script is also prone to SQL injections.

Comment: I believe the idea is to comma separate multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your question about adding `,`, just do

```
$new_user_id = $_COOKIE['user_id'];

if ($subs['subscribed_user_id'] === '') {
  $new_user_id = $subs['subscribed_user_id'] . ',' . $new_user_id;
}
```

With that said, the details of how you add the comma is not the issue here.

I began rewriting the code, but since the db interactions make the code hard to test and work with, I honestly couldn't be bothered to properly finish it.

You should

1. Wrap the functionality in a actual `function` taking parameters to remove use of `$_` globals.
2. Stop using the ancient and deprecated [`mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) extension. In fact, don't use (the much better) [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) either, at the very least, adopt [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), or better yet, a tool that removes the low level details of managing the DB.
3. Fix the [injection vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your update query.
4. Consider whether you really should be comma separating values in the column. Perhaps you should instead add a new row?

Some code I started writing, but didn't finish because I have better things to do than setting up the db I would need.

```
function update_user_id($user_id, $subs, $cookie) {
  $subs = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT subscribed_user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = " . (int) $user_id));

  $subs_array = explode(',', $subs['subscribed_user_id']);

  if (!in_array($cookie['user_id'], $subs_array)) {
    $new_user_id = $cookie['user_id'];

    if ($subs['subscribed_user_id'] === '') {
      $new_user_id = $subs['subscribed_user_id'] . ',' . $new_user_id;
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET subers = subers + 1, subscribed_user_id = '" . $new_user_id . "' WHERE user_id = ". (int) $user_id);
  }
}
```